# Auto complete not showing font family

Tags: php, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, autosuggest

I have called the font family and font face, But in Ajax Autocomplete content in drop down is not showing.

I want Exo2 and use like this

```
font-family: 'MyWebFont', Arial, sans-serif;

@font-face{ 
 font-family: 'MyWebFont';
 src: url('Exo2.0-Regular-webfont.eot');
 src: url('Exo2.0-Regular-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
     url('Exo2.0-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Exo2.0-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Exo2.0-Regular-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

Page content has changed according to Exo2 font, But drop down of autocomplete has not changed.
and when i find with font finder it shows

```
font-family (stack): Segoe UI
```

I have removed Segoe UI from all over the project, But not able to get Exo2 font in drop down of Autocomplete.

Any suggestion please.